# Create multiple td in a single ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem building a table.

at the moment I have code like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="...">
    <td>Some tds before</td>
    <td ng-repeat="foo in allFoo()">
        {{foo.v1}} ({{foo.v2}})
    </td>
    <td>Some tds after</td>
</tr>
```

What I really need is to build two columns in here. Somehow move that inner ng-repeat from the element an set it outside. something like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="...">
    <td>Some tds before</td>
    <foobar ng-repeat="foo in allFoo()">
       <td>{{foo.v1}}</td>
       <td>{{foo.v2}}</td>
    </foobar>
        <td>Some tds after</td>
</tr>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: How the final structure should be? and what is your data? can you provide it?

Answer (score 7):

Try this..

```
<tr ng-repeat="...">
    <td>Some tds before</td>
    <td ng-repeat-start="foo in allFoo()">{{foo.v1}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat-end>{{foo.v2}}</td>
    <td>Some tds after</td>
</tr>
```

Read more about `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

**Use a `<table>` within `<tr>` to build two columns**

```
<tr ng-repeat="...">
 <td>Some tds before</td>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Foo V1</th>
    <th>Foo v2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="foo in allFoo()">
    <td>{{ foo.v1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ foo.v2 }}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 <td>Some tds after</td>
</tr>
```